# Activemq does not balance messages after some time

Tags: java, apache-camel, jms, activemq-classic

I´m using `activemq(5.14.5)` with `camel(2.13.4)` because I still need `java 6`. 
I have a queue and 15 consumers. The messages sent to them are request reply.

When I start the consumers, the messages are distributed one per consumer as soon as the messages arrive but, after some time, only one consumer receives the messages, the others stay idle and a lot of messages stay pending.

The consumers have this configuration:

```
concurrentConsumers=15&maxMessagesPerTask=1&destination.consumer.prefetchSize=0&transferException=true
```

The time spent to process each message can varies a lot because of our business rule so, I don´t know if `activemq` has some rule that manage slow consumers and redirect to only one that is more "efficient".

The behaviour that I was expecting is that all the messages that arrives, start to process until all the consumers are full, but it is not what is happening.

Anybody knows what is happening?

Following is an image about what is happening:
[image: Queues]

Answer (score 1):

Your configuration has two eye-catching settings:

1. `maxMessagesPerTask=1`

If you did not intend to configure auto-scaling the threadpool, you should **remove this setting completely**. Is is by default unlimited and it sets how long to keep threads for processing (scaling up/down threadpool).

See also the [Spring Docs about this setting](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/listener/DefaultMessageListenerContainer.html#setMaxMessagesPerTask(int))

2. `prefetchSize=0`

Have you tried **setting this to 1** so that every consumer just gets 1 message at a time?

The [AMQ docs](http://activemq.apache.org/what-is-the-prefetch-limit-for.html) say about the prefetchSize:

> Large prefetch values are recommended for high performance with high message volumes. However, for lower message volumes, where **each message takes a long time to process, the prefetch should be set to 1**. This ensures that a consumer is only processing one message at a time. Specifying a **prefetch limit of zero, however, will cause the consumer to poll for messages, one at a time, instead of the message being pushed to the consumer**.

Comment: Hi, this maxMessagesPertask is there because I was using auto-scaling. I turned it off trying to solve the problem. Sorry, my mistake to leave this parameter. I tried the prefetchSize=1 but does not work too. I understood that prefetchSize=1 makes the consumer still keeps one message cached while it is processing another. This is a problem for me because the process takes so long and a message pending is a problem for me. Did I understand correct? I can try prefectchSize 1 again.

Comment: Sorry, you are right about the prefetchSize. Until now, I never saw value 0 for it and I misunderstood the docs.

Comment: There are [issues about slow consumers and selectors](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AMQ-2217). I see in your screenshot that you use selectors. Is it possible to start the consumers with the same options but without selectors and check if the message distribution is better?

Comment: Yes, i think that we can split the queues in different activemqs and the producers will redirect the messages so I can remove the selectors. Another suggestion is the workaround that is in the issue that you mentioned. Change the maxPageSize.<destinationPolicy>
            <policyMap>
                <policyEntries>
                    <policyEntry queue=">" maxPageSize="5000"/>
                </policyEntries>
            </policyMap>
        </destinationPolicy>

Comment: I added the policyEntry maxPageSize today in the activemq. Now it´s time to wait and check if it works. I will keep you informed.

Comment: The problem occurred again. And sooner than I thought. I'm not sure but it seems that increasing the max Page Size the error occurred sooner than the default configuration.

Comment: And removing the selectors did not help either?

Comment: This is the next step. I will change the endpoints and see what happens.

Comment: Consumers stated with no selectors. Let´s see what happens.

Comment: I removed the selectors but the problem still occurs. Only one consumer is receiving all the messages after some time. Any other idea?

Comment: Have you asked this question in the Camel user-list (http://camel.apache.org/mailing-lists.html)?